# Getting OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory while running OpenCV Sample Program: "stitching_detailed.cpp"

Tags: c++, memory, opencv

I recently starting working with OpenCV with the intent of stitching large amounts of images together to create massive panoramas. To begin my experimentation, I looked into the sample programs that come with the OpenCV files to get an idea about how to implement the OpenCV libraries. Since I was interested in image stitching, I went straight for the "stitching_detailed.cpp." The code can be found at:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp?rev=6856

Now, this program does most of what I need it to do, but I ran into something interesting. I found that for 9 out of 15 of the optional projection warpers, I receive the following error when I try to run the program:

```
    Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate XXXXXXXXXX bytes) in unknown function, 
    file C:\slave\winInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, 
    line 52
```

where the "X's" mark integer that change between the different types of projection (as though different methods require different amounts of space). The full source code for "alloc.cpp" can be found at the following website:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp?rev=3060

However, the line of code that emits this error in alloc.cpp is:

```
    static void* OutOfMemoryError(size_t size)
    {
    --HERE--> CV_Error_(CV_StsNoMem, ("Failed to allocate %lu bytes", (unsigned long)size));
        return 0;
    }
```

So, I am simply lost as to the possible reasons that this error may be occurring. I realize that this error would normally occur if the system is out of memory, but I when running this program with my test images I am never using more that ~3.5GB of RAM, according to my Task Manager.

Also, since the program was written as an sample of the OpenCV stitching capabilities BY OpenCV developers I find it hard to believe that there is a drastic memory error present within the source code.

Finally, the program works fine if I use some of the warping methods:

```
- spherical
- fisheye
- transverseMercator
- compressedPlanePortraitA2B1
- paniniPortraitA2B1 
- paniniPortraitA1.5B1)
```

but as ask the program to use any of the others (through the command line tag
--warp [PROJECTION_NAME]):

```
- plane
- cylindrical
- stereographic
- compressedPlaneA2B1
- mercator
- compressedPlaneA1.5B1
- compressedPlanePortraitA1.5B1
- paniniA2B1
- paniniA1.5B1
```

I get the error mentioned above. I get pretty good results from the transverseMercator project warper, but I would like to test the stereographic in particular. Can anyone help me figure this out?

The pictures that I am trying to process are 1360 x 1024 in resolution and my computer has the following stats:

```
Model: HP Z800 Workstation
Operating System: Windows 7 enterprise 64-bit OPS
Processor: Intel Xeon 2.40GHz (12 cores)
Memory: 14GB RAM
Hard Drive: 1TB Hitachi
Video Card: ATI FirePro V4800
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I run OpenCV's APP traincascade, i get just the same error as you:

```
Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate XXXXXXXXXX bytes) in unknown function, 
    file C:\slave\winInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, 
    line 52
```

at the time, only about 70% pecent of my RAM(6G) was occupied. And when runnig trainscascade step by step, I found that the error would be thrown.when it use about more than 1.5G RAM space.
then, I found the are two arguments which can control how many memory should be used:

> -precalcValBufSize 
>   -precalcIdxBufSize 
>   so i tried to set these two to 128, it run. I hope my experience can help you.

I thought this problem is nothing about memory leak, it is just relate to how many memory the OS limits a application occupy. I expect someone can check my guess.

Comment: I was having the same problem as you, I tried changing both `-precalcValBufSize` and `-precalcIdxBufSize` to 512, but it chnaged nothing.. I was out of idea until i saw your answer! Setting these parameters to 128 did worked for me and I wanted to take some time to thank you! (:

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had a similar issue with OpenCV image stitching. I've used create method to create stitcher instance and provided 5 images in vertical order to stitch method, but I've received insufficient memory error.

Panorama was successfully created after setting:

`setWaveCorrection(false)`

This solution will not be applicable if you need wave correction.

Comment: thank you. I used ```stitcher->setWaveCorrection(false);```, then no insufficient memory error

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the sequence of the stitching, I split a big picture into 3*3, and firstly I stitch them row by row and there is no problem, when I stitch them column by column, there is the problem same as you.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.